# Just-in-time debugger with ViewFinity/no admin rights

Tags: debugging, jit

My company uses ViewFinity to elevate processes that need admin rights in lieu of any kind of actual admin privileges. Visual studio is already elevated, but for some reason the JIT debugger doesn't run as admin. It is a separate .exe that kicks off when an exception occurs? How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT fixed the issue. Evidently when JIT debugger is launched, it launches a separate .exe (can't remember the name right now) which in turn launches visual studio.